django-channels integration tests with pytest?
I am trying to create a simple live-server style test fixture for pytest for testing with django-channels. I came up with the simplest solution:
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def channels_live_server(request):
    from channels.testing import ChannelsLiveServerTestCase

    class MyChannelsLiveServerTestCase(ChannelsLiveServerTestCase):
        @property
        def url(self):
            return self.live_server_url

    server = MyChannelsLiveServerTestCase()
    server._pre_setup()

    yield server

    server._post_teardown()

When used, the web server starts in the background and serves the web pages just fine... except it is using "production" settings, which means the database used is NOT the test database.
Any ideas how to fix this? I do realize, that multiprocessing at some later stage is using Popen and starts the server using spawn context. I am on macOS, if that matters.

With Django-chnanels 4.1 the problem with the default classes on my installation was, that the test database name was not set properly. So I needed to use this patch to have channels_live_server fixture in my code.
My solution is a simple and quick patch, because the whole issue looks like a part of a bigger problem, when the parent's process environment is not actually being copied into DaphneProcess environment via multiprocessing. Or perhaps some Django settings are being omitted in the process.
The only thing this code does is to setup a proper database name for testing, including when used with pytest-xdist.
from functools import partial

import pytest
from channels.testing import ChannelsLiveServerTestCase
from daphne.testing import DaphneProcess
from django.db.backends.base.creation import TEST_DATABASE_PREFIX


class PatchedDaphneProcess(DaphneProcess):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.test_db_name = kwargs.pop("test_db_name")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def run(self):
        from django.conf import settings

        settings.DATABASES["default"]["NAME"] = self.test_db_name
        return super().run()


class PatchedLiveServerTestCase(ChannelsLiveServerTestCase):
    # ProtocolServerProcess = PatchedDaphneProcess

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.test_db_name = kw.pop("test_db_name")
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)

    @property
    def ProtocolServerProcess(self):
        return partial(PatchedDaphneProcess, test_db_name=self.test_db_name)

    @property
    def url(self):
        return self.live_server_url


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def channels_live_server(request, transactional_db):
    def test_db_name():
        from django.conf import settings

        n = settings.DATABASES["default"].get("TEST", {}).get("NAME", None)
        if n:
            return n
        if settings.DATABASES["default"]["NAME"].startswith(TEST_DATABASE_PREFIX):
            return settings.DATABASES["default"]["NAME"]

        return TEST_DATABASE_PREFIX + settings.DATABASES["default"]["NAME"]

    server = PatchedLiveServerTestCase(test_db_name=test_db_name())
    server._pre_setup()

    yield server

    server._post_teardown()


